# Simultaneous eigenstate of commuting operators of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

there is a statement in quantummechanics (physics) that commuting Hermitian operators in Hilbert space have simultaneous eigenstates. There is another statement that these operators are inherited from a common operator.

For example, let A and B Hermitian operators with $AB=BA$. Then, there exists an operator $X$ that $A=a(X)$ and $B=b(X)$, where $a,b$ are functions. How could you prove these two statements?

Comment: For the first, note that if $Av = \alpha v$ then $ABv = BAv = B\alpha v = \alpha Bv$, so if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $Bv$ is another eigenvector for the same eigenvalue. For the second, I am unclear what you mean by "$a(X)$ where $a$ is a function". What sort of functions are you talking about? "Function" has a very wide definition in math, and for any two objects $u,v$ there are untold ways of defining a "function" $f$ with $f(u) = v$.